# C# & SQL Server 2012 parameterized insert not executing

Tags: c#, sql-server

When executing `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`, the local database does not populate, and contains no tables before or after the command. Is this a problem of the coding, or possibly the database set up? I can rows to the table manually, and then query and read from it, but not insert.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace FillGeologyDB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rock rock;
        List<Rock> rocks;
        string connectionString;
        string commandStatement;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rock = new Rock();
            rocks = new List<Rock>();
            connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BitMaintenance.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            commandStatement = "INSERT INTO Metamorphic (rock_Name, rock_Color, rock_Feature, rock_Mineral),"
            + "VALUES (@rock_Name, @rock_Color, @rock_Features, @rock_Mineral)";
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Metamorphic Rock.txt");
            while(reader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                rock.RockName = reader.ReadLine();
                rocks.Add(rock);   
            }
            reader.Close();

            int i = 0;
            reader = new StreamReader("Color.txt");
            while (reader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                rocks[i].RockColor = reader.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }
            reader.Close();

            i = 0;
            reader = new StreamReader("Features.txt");
            while (reader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                rocks[i].RockFeatures = reader.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }
            reader.Close();

            i = 0;
            reader = new StreamReader("Mineral.txt");
            while (reader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                rocks[i].RockMineral = reader.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {

           using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                foreach (Rock r in rocks)
                {
                    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStatement, connection))
                    {   
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Name", rock.RockName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Color", rock.RockColor);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Features", rock.RockFeatures);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Mineral", rock.RockMineral);
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch(SqlException ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it complains about this comma `rock_Mineral),`, not in anything in the data, just remove it.

Comment: A slight sidetrack from the issue at hand. You should read this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: It appears that the local database is creating new rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 commandStatement = "INSERT INTO Metamorphic (rock_Name, rock_Color, rock_Feature, rock_Mineral),"
            + "VALUES (@rock_Name, @rock_Color, @rock_Features, @rock_Mineral)";
```

You have `,` after before `VALUES` and also you don't have `" "` you should fix that. Also you can use symbol `@` to write string on more than one line:

```
commandStatement = @"INSERT INTO 
                         Metamorphic (rock_Name, rock_Color, rock_Feature, rock_Mineral)
                     VALUES 
                         (@rock_Name, @rock_Color, @rock_Features, @rock_Mineral)";
```

**PS: When you have question, add what is your problem. Not working is not a problem. The code return an exception which can be valuable to understand your problem. So you must always write the exception message in your question.**

Comment: The database is not showing any new rows after the code is ran, that is the problem.

Comment: @dachizzle37 I wrote you one mistake did you fix it ? Also not add records to the database, why did you catch an exception ? Did you debug it ?!

Comment: When I run the program, no records are added. I can't find an error to debug. Also, when I us the SQLServer amnagement studio to load the data from a flat file, nothing happens- no data is loaded. I am not sure if I have not set up the database correctly or what. I can enter rows manually and read them, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have created and run this locally, as mybirthname pointed out, it appears to have fixed the issue.

You may run this locally as an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = @"Your Connection string goes here";
        var commandStatement = "INSERT INTO Metamorphic (rock_Name, rock_Color, rock_Feature, rock_Mineral)"
        + "VALUES (@rock_Name, @rock_Color, @rock_Features, @rock_Mineral)";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandStatement, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Name", "One");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Color", "Two");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Features", "Thre");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rock_Mineral", "Four");
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did do some editing and left out the function call "LoadData()" as Nadia has pointed out. I have removed the comma in the parameterized statement. It works. Thank you!

Comment: Although, no I still see that the database has not inserted any new rows. And there is data in the file.